# Passing an argument to an R function for-loop statement

Tags: r

I am trying to create a for-loop in R to calculate the rate of "4-or-5 ratings" for each of the 20 movies in a dataset, with missing dating removed from the calcuation. I am having difficulty in taking an argument and concatenate it as a string into a statement.

```
testing_now <- function() {

  ## Load data
  data <- read.csv("A1Ratings.csv")

  ## Rename columns
  names(data) <- c("user","x260","x1210","x356","x318","x593","x3578","x1","x2028","x296","x1259","x2396","x2916","x780","x541","x1265","x2571","x527","x2762","x1198","x34")

  ## Remove "user" column
  new_data <- data[ , c(-1)]

  ## For-loop statements
  for (movieList in names(data)) {

    ## Test statement: This works
    print(movieList)

    ## The remaining statements are returning NULL and NaN
    print(new_data$movieList)
    print((sum(new_data$movieList ==4, na.rm=TRUE) + sum(new_data$movieList==5, na.rm=TRUE))/sum(!is.na(new_data$movieList)))

  }
}
```

Calling the function...

```
testing_now()
```

Result: ...
[1] "x260"
NULL
[1] NaN
...

Apparently the statements from "print(new_data$movieList)" and thereafter are not returning the desired output.

Comment: The column Movielist is not defined in the data frame.  If you want to programmatically access the column, you will need to use the [[ ]] notation.

Comment: you can't use new_data$movieList, you can use new_data[, movieList] though.

Comment: Thanks everyone! The [[ ]] notation helped and I am on my way to sort the movie list by ratings!